# Loop Limit in C/C++

Tags: c, loops

Is there a limit to how many times a loop can run in C?

```
void main()
{
    int T,N,x,X,i;
    x=0;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T>0)
    {
        T--;
        scanf("%d",&N);
        X=0;
        while(N>0)
        {
            N--;
            scanf("%d",&x);
            if(x>X){X=x;}
        }
        printf("Case: %d",x);
    }
}
```

T has a range of 0-250, and N has a range of 0-1000. x has a range of 0-10,000.
Whenever the N exceeds something above 800, my console stops taking input.
Can this be due to a limit on the input buffer?

Comment: For future reference: `int main()`, not `void main()`

Comment: In C it'd even be `int main(void)`.

Comment: There is a limit, but it's normally at least 10,002, so this program should be fine

Comment: @Tim Robinson: Mind citing that arbitrary number, for us?

Comment: @Thanatos, I wrote a program that looped. When it got to 10,001 it kept on going.

Comment: it's Microsoft's new VS licensing scheme. you must pay per loop iteration now.

Comment: Our elders tell of a young program much like this. It looped 300 times, then it looped 180 times, then... it looped 400 times! Do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit to how many times a loop may loop. There are limits to the max and minimum values of an `int`, and those may play into your loop. In this case, 800 should be fine, so there is something else going on here.

**Edit:** Works for me... the only weird thing I see is that you reset `X` inside the innermost loop, so the output is always the last integer entered if it's >0, or 0.

Comment: yeah, made a mistake there. hey could you do me a favor since your one's working.
paste the entire text of the file here into the console - http://terminusbound.com/e.in
if it doesn't hang then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Are you piping input to this program?  There may be some buffering limitation with that.  Try putting the data in a file and read from the file.

Comment: I'm pasting all at once. I guess you can call that piping.

Comment: Try piping the file to your program instead of pasting.  There may be a limit to how much data you can paste.

Comment: @tomlogic - You took the words right out of my mouth.  In other words, 100% agree.

Answer (score 1):

Because the comments have gone irreverent on you, I will make this a community wiki and commence with an interrogative-like suggestion that belongs in comments:

Check the return values from all `scanf` calls.  Do this first to determine whether the standard library API is already transmitting information to you -- via "electrostatic transmission", otherwise known as the contents of register `eax` after you call `scanf` on x86 architecture.  Do not let the light in that register die unobserved.  Take the register's electrical charges (bits) into a variable and compare them to both zero (0) and `EOF`.  Those alien transmission were sent to you from the year 1976, when `scanf` was first written to return an informative numerical value to the caller.

As tomlogic pointed out in comments to an answer, if you are pasting the data, you should instead try using the technique known as "input redirection" or "piping."  First, get your data into a file, let's say name *filename.dat*.  Then, issue a command such as the following:

`executable-name < filename.dat`

Where executable-name is the file you are generating with the C compiler.  Technically, the above syntax creates an "input redirection" or "stdin redirection" -- the shell opens the file for read access as file descriptor zero (0), also know as `stdin`.  The child program as spawned from the shell will `scanf` from the file, rather than the terminal (your paste buffer).

Another approach is to create a "pipe indirection" in which the shell opens another *process's* output for reading and passes this to the child, again as `stdin` file descriptor.  In this case, the shell probably uses `popen` rather than `open`.  The syntax for this might be:

`cat filename.dat | executable-name` as if on a Unix-clone, or

`type filename.dat | executable-name` if in the context of an IBM® PC-DOS® clone.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to loop 10,000 times or (much) more to compare the performance of two small calculations.

If there was a limit, there wouldn't be such as thing as an infinite loop. ;)